# Unable to add relationships to solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I recently created a solution in a CRM 8.2.5.4 on-premise org. I added the account entity to the solution along with a handful of unmanaged fields and N:1 relationships. Then I attempted to add unmanaged 1:N relationships to the solution. After selecting the relationships and proceeding through the wizard, it completes without error but does not add any relationships to the solution. The behavior is the same no matter which relationship(s) I select and whether or not I choose to add dependencies.

Is this a known issue, are there any workarounds?

Comment: that's strange. Is there any chance where you can install your custom solution over a trial org and try adding the relation there? Just to see what happens....

Comment: Also, try adding the N:1 side of the same relation. I think that should work?

Comment: Interestingly the relationships already appear in the solution from the N:1 side.

Comment: @ZachMast I've seen that same issue too

Comment: @ZachMast Try creating a new solution and then adding N:1 side of the relation only. Add the required components if it asks.